# General $n^{th}$ term of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is it possible to find a general formula or say a $n^{th}$ term formula for **any** arbitrary sequence? I have been trying to come up with a general $n^{th}$ term for the sequence $$0,\frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 0, \frac{1}{4},\frac{2}{4},\frac{3}{4},0,\frac{1}{5},\frac{2}{5} . . . $$

But so far I haven't been able to think of anything relevant. So I suppose every sequence can not be written in some general form. Am I correct? If not then can anyone give me a general $n^{th}$ term for the above-given sequence?

Comment: You can write a computer program that generates this sequence, and then convert this program into a formula (which is possible for any program).

Comment: Hint: break it down into separate sequences for the numerators $0,1,0,1,2,0,1,2,3,...$ and denominators $2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,...$.

Comment: Given any finite sequence, there exists a polynomial $p(x)$ such that $p(i) = a_i.$  Which means that we can plausibly suggest 17 as the next number in the sequence for any given partial sequence.

Comment: @dxiv: I think that the correct terminology is *denominator*.

Comment: @barakmanos Duh. I mean, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sequence shows runs of equal denominators of increasing length and increasing value.

The run lengths are $2,3,4,5\cdots$ and starting indexes $0,2,5,9,14,\cdots$ i.e. $(k^2+3k)/2$. The key is to invert this relation

$$\frac{k^2+3k}2=n,$$ or $$k=\frac{\sqrt{8n+9}-3}2.$$

Then the denominators are

$$q:=\lfloor k\rfloor+2.$$

For every run, the numerators are the integers increasing from $0$, i.e. the term index minus the index of the start of the run,

$$p:=n-\frac{\lfloor k\rfloor^2+3\lfloor k\rfloor}2.$$

Hence the general term,

$$t_n=\frac{2n-\left\lfloor\dfrac{\sqrt{8n+9}-3}2\right\rfloor^2-3\left\lfloor\dfrac{\sqrt{8n+9}-3}2\right\rfloor}{2\left\lfloor\dfrac{\sqrt{8n+9}-3}2\right\rfloor+4}.$$

Comment: I didn't get the last 2 steps but still it was helpful. Thanks..

Comment: @Dark_Knight: try a few numerical examples.